# Extender plugin jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou trabalhando num projeto que utiliza a library [X-editable](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) com Bootstrap 3. Ao longo da página são várias instâncias do plugin, todavia, houve a necessidade que algumas instâncias tivessem um template diferente. Lendo a documentação da biblioteca descobri que posso fazer as modificações através de:

```
$.fn.editableform.buttons
```

Porém isso acaba afetando todos os outros X-editables da página. Minha questão aqui é de como posso fazer essa modificação apenas para determinadas instâncias. Há como estender esse plugin e alterar esse comportamento padrão, sendo referenciado como algo assim:

```
$(selector).customEditable();
```

Realmente não sei muito de jQuery, o que tenho até agora é o seguinte:

```
(function($){
$.fn.customEditable = function(options) {

    // var defaults = {
        editableform = {
            buttons: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm editable-trigger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button>',
        }
    // };

    var options = $.extend({}, editableform, options);

    //Here you can create your extended functions, just like a base plugin.

    return this.each(function() {

        //Execute your normal plugin
        $(this).editable(options);

        console.log('customEditable');
    });
};

})(jQuery);
```

Porém ainda assim isso não consigo fazer o overwrite de editableform.buttons para esse plugin customizado!

Comment: veja se é isso http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/fGU58/23/ =D

Comment: Mas como eu poderia fazer para ter um xeditable diferente dos restantes, sem usar o $.fn.editableform.buttons globalmente

Answer (score 6):

**Exemplo**

Nesse exemplo você pode usar um class especifica para indicar quem terá o comportamento customizado. No exemplo que montei usei a class 'editableCustom'.

**Funcionamento**

O funcionamento do código é bem simples. Sobreescrevi a parte do plugin que mostra os botões de forma a verificar se existe a class 'editableCustom' no elemento que mostrará a popover. Caso exista ele mostrar a popover com os dados da variável 'editableCustom'. Essa variável contém o modelo customizado.

```js
$.fn.editableform.customButtons = 
    '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success editable-submit"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i></button>'+
    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger editable-cancel"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>'+
    '<button type="button" class="btn editable-cancel3 editable-remove"><i class="icon-trash"></i></button>';
    
$.extend($.fn.editableform.Constructor.prototype, {
    initButtons: function() {
        var el = this.options.scope;
        var isCustom = $(el).hasClass("editableCustom");
        
        var $btn = this.$form.find('.editable-buttons');
        $btn.append($.fn.editableform[isCustom? 'customButtons' : 'buttons']);
        
        if(this.options.showbuttons === 'bottom') {
            $btn.addClass('editable-buttons-bottom');
        }
        
        this.$form.find('.editable-submit').button({
            icons: { primary: "ui-icon-check" },
            text: false
        }).removeAttr('title');
        this.$form.find('.editable-cancel').button({
            icons: { primary: "ui-icon-closethick" },
            text: false
        }).removeAttr('title');
    }
});

$('.editableDefault,.editableCustom').editable();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/assets/x-editable/bootstrap-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/assets/x-editable/bootstrap-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js"></script>

<h4>X-editable: display checklist as UL</h4>
<ul id='lista'>
    <li class='editableDefault'>Editable Default</li>
    <li class='editableDefault'>Editable Default</li>
    <li class='editableCustom'>Editable Custom</li>
    <li class='editableCustom'>Editable Custom</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Obrigado era exatamente isso que estava procurando, muito obrigado!